# What is the relationship between Flutter Engine and Dart VM?

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the relationship between **Dart VM** and the **Flutter Engine**?

- A really detailed document, [mrale.ph/dartvm](https://mrale.ph/dartvm/) on the Dart VM doesn't mention the Flutter Engine.
- The FlutterEngine documentation ([iOS](https://api.flutter.dev/objcdoc/Classes/FlutterEngine.html), [Android](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/embedding/engine/FlutterEngine.html))/ source code mentions dart VM in some docstrings, but not in much depth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **FlutterEngine**: It has a single execution context, and controls a dart isolate. If a new FlutterEngine is created, a new Dart isolate is created.

The **Dart VM**: To know more about the Dart VM, I found the [header file, `dart_vm.h`](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/master/runtime/dart_vm.h). The dart VM contains an isolate name server, where different isolates can find each other, kind of like DNS. There is only ever 1 Dart VM running per process. All Dart isolates share the VM. In *"What are types good for, anyway. How the Dart 2 typesystem influenced the Dart VM?"*, a developer said that **Dart VM = Dart Compiler + Dart runtime**.

### On Android

The `FlutterEngine`'s constructor uses a `FlutterJNI` class to talk to the C++ Dart VM code. It uses the Dart VM to manage the isolates and execute the code. This includes assigning which OS threads run which isolate.

It goes through the [JNI](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni) to interop with C++ because Android runs in a virtual machine.

### On iOS

On iOS, the FlutterEngine directly calls [`shell.RunEngine`](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/0ba39de139a209d124f52d7a0c692cb745fa4a44/shell/common/shell.h#L201-L203), where `shell` is `flutter::Shell` in the C++ code. Again, it uses the Dart VM to manage isolates/ execute code. (I need to read more about this and elaborate )

The DartVM is accessed directly in iOS, because iOS supports Objective-C++, where Objective-C and C++ code can pretty much coexist.

Comment: When a new flutter engine is created a new isolate is created, that makes sense, but what about vice-versa? Does each isolate run in a separate flutter engine? For instance when I do `Isolate.spawn`, it runs in the same isolate group, but will it be the same flutter engine or different?

Comment: Those isolates would share the same flutter engine

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have gone through almost the entire C code base and Android API docs to figure this out, but couldn't. Can you share resource from where you got to know this information?

Comment: By default, there is only ever 1 flutter engine. In your question, you're just using isolates, it's a simple use case. Only in advanced use cases would you **manually** run multiple. It's not explicitly stated anywhere but nowhere will mention multiple engines running.

Comment: Thanks makes sense. Thanks. Also, I just noticed you asked the question and then answered on the same date and same time. Kinda strange

Comment: Sure, no worries. Though answering your own question is not strange, it's common practice on Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is about sharing knowledge, even if you answer your own question. Here's another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70761192/docker-compose-equivalent-of-docker-run-gpu-all-option/70761193#70761193