# Docker compose equivalent of `docker run --gpu=all` option

Tags: docker-compose

To automate the configuration (`docker run` arguments) used to launch a docker container, I am writing a `docker-compose.yml` file.

My container should have access to the GPU, and so I currently use `docker run --gpus=all` parameter. This is described in the [Expose GPUs for use](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/) docs:

> Include the `--gpus` flag when you start a container to access GPU
> resources. Specify how many GPUs to use. For example:
>
> $  docker run -it --rm --gpus all ubuntu nvidia-smi

Unfortunately, [Enabling GPU access with Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gpu-support/) doesn't describe this use case exactly. This guide uses the `deploy` yaml element, but in the context of reserving machines with GPUs. In fact, [another documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#deploy) says that it will be ignored by `docker-compose`:

> This only takes effect when deploying to a swarm with docker stack deploy, and **is ignored by** docker-compose up and docker-compose run.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

After trying it and solving a myriad of problems along the way, I have realized that it is simply the documentation that is out of date.

Adding the following yaml block to my `docker-compose.yml` resulted in `nvidia-smi` being available to use.

```
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - driver: nvidia
              count: 1
              capabilities: [gpu]
```

Comment: Thanks; been trying to figure this out for ages

Comment: A link to the documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/gpu-support/

Comment: They've since updated their docs: `The following
sub-options only takes effect when deploying to a swarm with docker stack deploy, and is ignored by docker-compose up and docker-compose run, **except for resources**.` Therefore, their documentation is now "up to date", but more complicated.

Comment: I'm literally starting every new project by copy-pasting code from this answer. I just can't remember all this boilerplate.

Comment: I love you I love you I love you

Comment: setting `count: all` gives you all gpus according to the documentation.