# In Docker Compose file, how to enable GPU in service build instructions?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gpu, nvidia-docker

I am trying to build service from docker file when start docker compose. The docker-compose.yml looks like:

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    shm_size: 4gb
# ...
```

The build process need to enable GPU. I know how to enable GPU in `deploy` according to this [blog](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gpu-support/). But it seems docker compose file build do not support GPU.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70761192/docker-compose-equivalent-of-docker-run-gpu-all-option

Answer (score 0):

I think, I have read two different method.
The simple, try that:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/gpu-support/
https://www.tremplin-numerique.org/en/how-to-run-compose-docker-containers-with-gpu-access

```
  services:
  test:
    image: nvidia/cuda:10.2-base
    command: nvidia-smi
    runtime: nvidia
```

The complex,
It run a docker via a run.
Then via docker compose, it connect to its docker.

In this method, it describes all steps.
https://dinhanhthi.com/docker-gpu/

```
docker run \
    --gpus all\
    --name docker_thi_test\
    --rm\
    -v abc:abc\
    -p 8888:8888
```

**Yaml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  jupyter:
    container_name: 'docker_thi_test'
    build: .
    volumes:
        - ./notebooks:/tf/notebooks 

    ports:
        - 8888:8888 

    environment:
        - NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 

        - PASSWORD=12345
```

Comment: The link to dinhanhthi.com has changed, it's now: https://dinhanhthi.com/note/docker-gpu/